# Can't find static function local_apic_timer_interrupt in /proc/kallsyms

Tags: c, kernel

I am new to kernel programming and I am trying to write a program about APIC. I find `smp_apic_timer_interrupt` in `/proc/kallsyms` but I can't find `local_apic_timer_interrupt` in kallsyms by command: `grep local_apic_timer_interrupt /proc/kallsyms`. My kernel version is V4.15 and `apic.c` has definitions for both `local_apic_timer_interrupt` and `smp_apic_timer_interrupt`.

Does anyone know why I can't find `local_apic_timer_interrupt` in `kallsyms` and what's the difference between `local_apic_timer_interrupt` and `smp_apic_timer_interrupt`?

Comment: The names of static functions are not external symbols.  I'm not certain about the semantics of `/proc/kallsyms`, but it's entirely plausible that it informs only about external symbols.

Comment: In Linux source code, I also found this function : static void lapic_timer_broadcast(const struct cpumask *mask)  which is also a static function, but I could still find this in kallsyms. Quite confusing.

Comment: But for some static functions, they can not be found in kallsyms( I've checked some static functions), I guess there is some rules for mapping these kernel functions into kallsyms. Thanks for your help !